# How to summon a falling_block (command_block) that is facing east?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried:

```
/summon falling_block {Block:command_block 2,Time:1}
```

but it says:

> [16:09:26] Data tag parsing failed: Expected '}' but got '2' at:
>   {Block:command_block 2<--[HERE]

If I use:

```
/summon falling_block {Block:command_block,Time:1}
```

it succeeds but then it is facing down.

Comment: Does adding the tag "Data:4" help? I think that's the metadata of the block, but I can't test it right now. If it works, I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the [block data](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Block_data) in order to rotate it.  In your case, east would be 5.  You do this by adding `Data` to your command.  I also added coordinate information.

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~1 {Block:"minecraft:command_block",Time:1,Data:5}
```

Here is a list of block data from the wiki linked above:

- 0: facing down
- 1: facing up
- 2: facing north
- 3: facing south
- 4: facing west
- 5: facing east

Comment: Answer needs to be updated for 1.13